# is there a Range in Ruby like x-y not x .. y

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve [Range Extraction](https://www.codewars.com/kata/range-extraction/train/ruby)

each time i click Attempt i see that

```
Test Results:
✘ Expected: "-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20", instead got: [-6, -3..1, 3..5, 7..11, 14, 15, 17..20]
```

so what is the different between `-3-1` and `-3..1` ? is that a bug ?
this is the first day i write Ruby so i can not judge 
this is my code

```
def solution(list)
  result = []
  arr = []
  list.each.with_index{
    |x,index|
    arr.push(x)
    if index == list.length-1
      result.push(arr)
      break
    end

    if list[index + 1] - x != 1
      result.push(arr)
      arr = []
    end
  }
  final = []
  result.each{
    |x|
    if x.length >= 3
      final.push(Range.new(x[0],x[-1]))
    else
      final.concat(x)
    end
  }
   final
end

puts solution([-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20]).inspect
# returns "-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20"` is a string, `[-6, -3..1, 3..5, 7..11, 14, 15, 17..20]` is an array of ranges and integers.

You can replace the final line of your `solution` method to coerce the array to the required format:

```
final.map do |x|
  if x.is_a? Range
    [x.min, x.max].join("-")
  else
    x.to_s
  end
end.join(",")
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [`slice_when`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), you can write a shorter and more Ruby-ish solution:

```
def solution(list)
  list.slice_when { |x, y| y > x + 1 }.flat_map do |neighbors|
    if neighbors.size > 2
      "#{neighbors.first}-#{neighbors.last}"
    else
      neighbors
    end
  end.join(',')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other ways.

```
array = [-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 17]
```

**#1 Use `Enumerable#chunk_while`**

[Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) (new in Ruby v2.3) is the flip side of [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (new in Ruby v2.2), which @Eric used in his answer.

```
array.chunk_while { |x,y| y == x+1 }.map { |a|
  a.size == 1 ? a.first.to_s : "#{ a.first }-#{ a.last }" }.join(",")
  #=> "-6,-3-0,3,5,7-9,14-15,17"
```

Note that

```
array.chunk_while { |a,b| b == a+1 }.to_a
  #=> [[-6], [-3, -2, -1, 0], [3], [5], [7, 8, 9], [14, 15], [17]]
```

**#2 Step through the array**

```
first, *rest = array
rest.each_with_object([[first]]) { |n, arr|
  (n == arr.last.last+1) ? (arr.last << n) : (arr << [n]) }.
  map { |a| (a.size == 1)? a.first.to_s : "#{ a.first }-#{ a.last }" }.join(",")
  #=> "-6,-3-0,3,5,7-9,14-15,17"
```